# How can we parse inner node of json response in Flutter app?

Tags: json, flutter, jsonresponse

I'm having this response

```
"countryitems": [
            {
                    "1": {
                            "ourid": 1,
                            "title": "Afghanistan",
                            "code": "AF",
                    },
                    "2": {
                            "ourid": 2,
                            "title": "Albania",
                            "code": "AL",
                    },
                    "3": {
                            "ourid": 3,
                            "title": "Algeria",
                            "code": "DZ",                        },
                    "4": {
                            "ourid": 4,
                            "title": "Angola",
                            "code": "AO",
                    }
           }
]
```

For question, I've put only 4 nodes where actually I've 150 around of nodes. I'm not getting how can I parse to get country names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution. You have to decode the response with `jsonDecode` and generating a map out of the response. If you iterate through the map, you can access the inner nodes.

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

var jsonString = 
""" 
{
  "countryitems": [
    {
      "1": {
        "ourid": 1,
        "title": "Afghanistan",
        "code": "AF"
      },
      "2": {
        "ourid": 2,
        "title": "Albania",
        "code": "AL"
      },
      "3": {
        "ourid": 3,
        "title": "Algeria",
        "code": "DZ"
      },
      "4": {
        "ourid": 4,
        "title": "Angola",
        "code": "AO"
      }
    }
  ]
}
""";

void main() {
  Map<String, dynamic> obj = json.decode(jsonString)['countryitems'][0];

  // print out all country names in obj
  for(int i = 1; i <= obj.length; i++) {
    print(obj['$i']['title']);
  }
}
```

Comment: I just wanted to write the exact same thing :)

Comment: I would definitely try this one.

Comment: It's a perfect way to handle such response. It did work well.

Answer (score 0):

'dart:convert' is good for simple cases.

But when you need true flexibility and less boilerplate, I'd suggest to use this library instead https://github.com/k-paxian/dart-json-mapper